# After gcsfuse mounting of a bucket transferred from S3 using Cloud Storage Transfer service, the s3 bucket fail to show when issuing a ls command.

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I transferred a S3 bucket to GCS using Transfer Service. The transfer went well. From cloud console, I can see the s3 bucket. However, after I use gcsfuse to mount the GCS bucket (with the transferred s3 bucket inside) in a GCE VM, it fails to appear in ls command.

Any idea I can fix the problem???

Thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the documentation [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/941ac7e9afb3ef89a51100e10b418e1f90c22388/docs/semantics.md#implicit-directories) about implicit directories. You likely have objects named `foo/bar`, but gcsfuse will not show a directory named `foo` unless there is an object in your bucket named `foo/`.

You can work around this with `--implicit-directories`, but there are drawbacks. See the link above.